# How can I highlight invalid inputs if they are part of a disabled ancestor?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Parameters A and C have invalid inputs but only C gets highlighted. Is there a way to ensure that parameter A does as well?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
body, input, select { 
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}
span.field {
  display:  block;
  position: relative;
}
form {
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}
input:invalid, fieldset:disabled input:invalid {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
fieldset:disabled {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<fieldset name="a" disabled="">
  <legend>Disabled elements</legend>
<span class="field">
  <label for="A" >Parameter A</label>
  <input name="A" type="number" required="" min="0" step="any" value="-3"> <span class="units">s</span>
</span>
<span class="field">
  <label for="B" >Parameter B</label>
  <input name="B" type="number" required="" min="0" step="any" value="3"> <span class="units">s</span>
</span>
</fieldset>
<fieldset name="b" >
  <legend>Enabled elements</legend>
<span class="field">
  <label for="C" >Parameter C</label>
  <input name="C" type="number" required="" min="0" step="any" value="-3"> <span class="units">s</span>
</span>
<span class="field">
  <label for="D" >Parameter D</label>
  <input name="D" type="number" required="" min="0" step="any" value="3"> <span class="units">s</span>
</span>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the trick is that the input become also `:disabled` and no more `:invalid`

Comment: Your label won’t work as you don’t specify id on input, either add id or move input into label. As far as css goes...if you want to have it cross browser compatible do the check via js and add valid/invalid classes

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. When disabled, form fields does not apply validation CSS rules as they can't be modified, so it makes no sense.
Once you enable that fieldset, you'll see the proper style applied.

Comment: You mean that it (the behavior of CSS) works as designed. But that's not what I want. I need to draw the user's attention to any state that may be problematic, and even if the resulting elements are disabled, they're still there and they contain an invalid entry.

Comment: Well, then you go against the W3C recommendations for usability an accessibility. Think that what you want might be more a problem than a solution, as highlighting an input as not valid is a Call to Action. An action that the user is not going to be able to accomplish as the form is disabled. Which is confuse.
However, let me know more about the whole user flow / journey and I'll be able to suggest you a solution. Why is disabled?